# Accelerating performance of loop performing unsigned long long modulo operation

Tags: c, performance, loops, modulus, long-long

I need to perform a many operations of finding remainders of the division `unsigned long long` number by the 16-bit modulus:

```
unsigned long long largeNumber;
long residues[100];
unsigned long modules[100];
intiModules(modules); //set different 16-bit values

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
     residues[i] = largeNumber % modules[i];
}
```

How I can accelerate this loop?

The iteration count is not large (32-128), but this loop performed very often so its speed is critical.

Comment: I don't think you can do much here. Maybe hand coding it in assembler might help a bit. But anyway 100 is not really "many".

Comment: One option is to use pthreads to execute many modulus operations in parallel.

Comment: If your modules values range is continuous then you can have just one variable to store it and then decrement that variable in the loop.
For eg, if your values are in the range (high,low), then `for(i=low, { i<=high,i++); residue[i-low]=largeNumber%i; }`

Comment: What is the return value of `intiModules`? If it's 16 bit then storing it to short **may** be faster since the longer the division, the longer the latency (according to Agner Fog's table). Also, use SIMD and multiprocessing will enhance the performance

Comment: Does `unsigned long modules[100] = intiModules();` really works?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc % operation illy vectorize, i think.

Comment: @leeduhem this notation i write for example.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  i need often perform this cycle

Comment: @user2810512 This is confusing. Anyway, you could write something like `unsigned long modules[100]; initModules(modules);` for the same purpose.

Comment: @leeduhem thanks, i corrected topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Division by a constant (and there are only 65536 of them) can be performed by multiplication of the reciprocal followed/preceded by some fine-tuning. Since this method is accurate for a limited range, one can use some techniques to reduce the 64-bit operand to a much smaller value (which is still congruent to the original value):

```
// pseudo code -- not c
a = 0x1234567890abcdefULL;
a = 0x1234 << 48 + 0x5678 << 32 + 0x90ab << 16 + 0xcdef;

a % N === ((0x1234 * (2^48 % N) +     // === means 'is congruent'
           (0x5678 * (2^32 % N)) +    // ^ means exponentation
           (0x90ab * (2^16 % N)) + 
           (0xcdef * 1)) % N;
```

The intermediate value can be calculated with (small) multiplications only and the final remainder (%N) has potential to be calculated with reciprocal multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

If speed is critical, according to this [answer about branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349211/when-if-ever-is-loop-unrolling-still-useful), loop unrolling may be of help, avoiding the test induced by the *for* instruction, reducing the number of tests and improving "branch prediction".

The gain (or none, some compilers do that optimization for you) varies based on architecture / compiler.

On my machine, changing the loop while preserving the number of operations from

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++){
    residues[i % 100] = largeNumber % modules[i % 100];
}
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500000000; i+=5){
    residues[(i+0) % 100] = largeNumber % modules[(i+0) % 100];
    residues[(i+1) % 100] = largeNumber % modules[(i+1) % 100];
    residues[(i+2) % 100] = largeNumber % modules[(i+2) % 100];
    residues[(i+3) % 100] = largeNumber % modules[(i+3) % 100];
    residues[(i+4) % 100] = largeNumber % modules[(i+4) % 100];
}
```

with `gcc -O2` the gain is ~15%. (500000000 instead of 100 to observe a more significant time difference)

Comment: I doubt 'i < x' is the real bottleneck; Also I doubt that e.g. IA can execute multiple DIV operations in parallel -- which is the issue I tried to address. But overall, this is an excellent technique to try, as it's just so plain simple.