# Is there a speed difference at execution between writing n following operations or using a for looping from 0 to n?

Tags: c, for-loop, time

Let's say I have to do the same operation `op` on the n+1 elements of an array `arr`.

Is there a difference of speed at execution between :

```
op(arr[0]);
op(arr[1]);
...
op(arr[n]);
```

and

```
for(i=0; i<=n; i++) {
     op(arr[i]);
}
```

Or is the compiler smart enough to detect the for loop (given n is fixed at compile time) and convert it to the linear execution (if it is actually faster)?

Comment: Look up *loop unrolling* optimization..

Comment: Measure, profile, read the generated code.

Comment: Yes.. this is an optimization technique - Unrolling. You can verify by repeating this for large n's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When, if ever, is loop unrolling still useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349211/when-if-ever-is-loop-unrolling-still-useful)

Comment: @pmg that's an error from my part, I'll correct the code

Comment: @Balocre I'd expect modern compilers to be smart enough. I don't think you should worry about such micro-optimizations, sacrificting readablitiy. That is, unless your program doesn't work fast enough, *and you can prove with time measurements that unrolling the loop manually will help*

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Even if there's a speed difference, most of the time it's irrelevant, only worry about this if you actually have a performance problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is the compiler smart enough to ....

Yes.  Many compilers are far better at such micro optimizations that coders.

This loop or unrolled loop micro-optimization depends on the possessor - some will be faster one way, some the other. Best to code for clarity and let the compiler optimize. If the compiler does not optimize well, more effective to research a new compiler (or its options) than craft code.

---

Yet for a select situation and with a very knowledgeable coder, crafted code *may* be better.  But that takes time that could be spent with larger efficiency issues.

Problem with crafted code (faster code but looks strange) include: higher maintenance cost, convoluted-ness make for difficult optimization on another platforms, higher bug rate.  So the crafted solution may work faster today, yet slower with the next compiler update.