# Why does 2x2 loop unrolling run slower in python (but not when compiled with jit nopython)

Tags: python, optimization, jit, loop-unrolling

These functions provide identical results (assuming an even length array). The 2x2 unrolled function, however runs 30% slower when fed 10,000,000 floats. When I change the functions to run in nopython mode I see approximately a 2.5x speedup with the unrolled function.

**Why does normal python fail to gain a speedup from loop unrolling?** What's the underlying difference in how these two versions of the code are compiled and run?

```py
# @jit(nopython=True)
def func1(array):
    numSum = 0

    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        numSum += array[i]

    return numSum

# 2x2 unrolled
# @jit(nopython=True)
def unrolledFunc1(array):
    numSum0 = 0
    numSum1 = 0 

    for i in range(0, array.shape[0]-1, 2):
        numSum0 += array[i] 
        numSum1 += array[i+1] 

    numSum = numSum0 + numSum1 

    return numSum
```

Comment: On my PC, `unrolledFunc1` runs 3% faster in python. How did you benchmark them?

Comment: Why bother about loop unrolling in case of the provided code? Why not use `sum(array)`?

Comment: @ken :   I suppose that unrolledFunc1 speed will highly depend on used hardware, the compiler used to create the Python executable, Python version, ... In this context your experience might differ from OP's without being caused by the way of benchmarking.

Comment: @ken Regardless the speedup is minor. Supposedly with code like this I should expect a significant (~2x) performance boost. Also doesn't explain why the speedup is much larger in nopython mode.

Comment: @Claudio It's just a thought experiment. I saw this while I was playing around with some code and was curious at why there was no speedup and what the underlying implementation in python is.

Comment: @BryanTurns : without the very details of your system (OS, CPU, Memory, compiler used to obtain the Python executable and it's options, Python version, ...) it will be hard to guess why it is as it is what you observe. The answer by *Epic Coder* explains this in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you're doing loop unrolling wrong (search for `duff's device`).

Secondly, Python has A LOT of overhead when accessing array elements (out-of-bounds check, wraparound check, etc, etc.) which is where most of the program time is spent, not the actual addition.

Thirdly, you can use `dis.dis` or other Python disassembler tools to see the generated byte codes and see what exactly the differences are between the unrolled and normal loop (not much difference in most cases since the bulk of the CPU time is "wasted" performing checks).

Lastly, loop unrolling will not have ANY improvements on modern hardware! You may be surprised but a for loop is actually a while loop, which in machine code is something like:

```
loop_begin:
    i = 0
    target = 100
repeated_section:
    if i < target:
        # DO SOME PROCESSING
        i = i+1
        jump to repeated_section
```

If you don't believe me, search for `Python while else`. Modern hardware is tuned to predict branches and do as much processing as it can ahead of time. Since in a for loop, the branch is extremely well predictable (it's always true except for the very last iteration), the branch predictor optimizes your loop without you realizing it. I'm not sure how exactly you ran your benchmarks but I used Cython and wrote a bunch of variations for loop unrolling (manually unrolling 100 loops, using Duff's device and normal loop) and they all had very similar run times (within the margin of error of each other), especially if you use the correct compiler flags (-O3 or -Ofast for GCC on Linux or /O2i for visual studio c++ compiler on windows).

If you're using black magic (@jit) I wouldn't worry about the performance differences from their generated code. You should try to make the jit compiler understand what you're trying to do, so it can optimize it for you. That being said if you're truly trying to optimize code rather than just trying jit and checking what sticks, you need to control the actual source code, compiler flags, etc. BEFORE running benchmarks so you can get a sense of what your change did AND YOU MUST USE A PROFILER to see WHAT IS ACTUALLY THE BOTTLENECK in your code, not guess and check.

This is explained similarly here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349219/22723166

Edit:
I ran a quick sanity check on your specific example (just calculating the sum). Keep in mind this only works for arrays that are exact multiples of N (N being the number of unrolled lines) since I didn't bother with a proper duff's device; this is just meant to be a sanity check:

```
cpdef  loop_sum(double [::1] arr):
    cdef unsigned int i = 0
    cdef double total = 0
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        total += arr[i]
    return total

cpdef  unroll_10_sum(double [::1] arr):
    cdef unsigned int i = 0, shape = arr.shape[0]
    cdef double total0 = 0, total1 = 0, total2 = 0, total3 = 0, total4 = 0, total5 = 0, total6 = 0, total7 = 0, total8 = 0, total9 = 0
    for i in range(0,shape,10):
        total0 += arr[i]
        total1 += arr[i+1]
        total2 += arr[i+2]
        total3 += arr[i+3]
        total4 += arr[i+4]
        total5 += arr[i+5]
        total6 += arr[i+6]
        total7 += arr[i+7]
        total8 += arr[i+8]
        total9 += arr[i+9]
    return total0+total1+total2+total3+total4+total5+total6+total7+total8+total9
   
cpdef  unroll_100_sum(double [::1] arr):
    cdef unsigned int i = 0, shape = arr.shape[0]
    cdef double total0 = 0, total1 = 0, total2 = 0, total3 = 0, total4 = 0, total5 = 0, total6 = 0, total7 = 0, total8 = 0, total9 = 0, total10 = 0, total11 = 0, total12 = 0, total13 = 0, total14 = 0, total15 = 0, total16 = 0, total17 = 0, total18 = 0, total19 = 0, total20 = 0, total21 = 0, total22 = 0, total23 = 0, total24 = 0, total25 = 0, total26 = 0, total27 = 0, total28 = 0, total29 = 0, total30 = 0, total31 = 0, total32 = 0, total33 = 0, total34 = 0, total35 = 0, total36 = 0, total37 = 0, total38 = 0, total39 = 0, total40 = 0, total41 = 0, total42 = 0, total43 = 0, total44 = 0, total45 = 0, total46 = 0, total47 = 0, total48 = 0, total49 = 0, total50 = 0, total51 = 0, total52 = 0, total53 = 0, total54 = 0, total55 = 0, total56 = 0, total57 = 0, total58 = 0, total59 = 0, total60 = 0, total61 = 0, total62 = 0, total63 = 0, total64 = 0, total65 = 0, total66 = 0, total67 = 0, total68 = 0, total69 = 0, total70 = 0, total71 = 0, total72 = 0, total73 = 0, total74 = 0, total75 = 0, total76 = 0, total77 = 0, total78 = 0, total79 = 0, total80 = 0, total81 = 0, total82 = 0, total83 = 0, total84 = 0, total85 = 0, total86 = 0, total87 = 0, total88 = 0, total89 = 0, total90 = 0, total91 = 0, total92 = 0, total93 = 0, total94 = 0, total95 = 0, total96 = 0, total97 = 0, total98 = 0, total99 = 0
    for i in range(0,shape,100):
        total0 += arr[i]
        total1 += arr[i+1]
        total2 += arr[i+2]
        total3 += arr[i+3]
        total4 += arr[i+4]
        total5 += arr[i+5]
        total6 += arr[i+6]
        total7 += arr[i+7]
        total8 += arr[i+8]
        total9 += arr[i+9]
        total10 += arr[i+10]
        total11 += arr[i+11]
        total12 += arr[i+12]
        total13 += arr[i+13]
        total14 += arr[i+14]
        total15 += arr[i+15]
        total16 += arr[i+16]
        total17 += arr[i+17]
        total18 += arr[i+18]
        total19 += arr[i+19]
        total20 += arr[i+20]
        total21 += arr[i+21]
        total22 += arr[i+22]
        total23 += arr[i+23]
        total24 += arr[i+24]
        total25 += arr[i+25]
        total26 += arr[i+26]
        total27 += arr[i+27]
        total28 += arr[i+28]
        total29 += arr[i+29]
        total30 += arr[i+30]
        total31 += arr[i+31]
        total32 += arr[i+32]
        total33 += arr[i+33]
        total34 += arr[i+34]
        total35 += arr[i+35]
        total36 += arr[i+36]
        total37 += arr[i+37]
        total38 += arr[i+38]
        total39 += arr[i+39]
        total40 += arr[i+40]
        total41 += arr[i+41]
        total42 += arr[i+42]
        total43 += arr[i+43]
        total44 += arr[i+44]
        total45 += arr[i+45]
        total46 += arr[i+46]
        total47 += arr[i+47]
        total48 += arr[i+48]
        total49 += arr[i+49]
        total50 += arr[i+50]
        total51 += arr[i+51]
        total52 += arr[i+52]
        total53 += arr[i+53]
        total54 += arr[i+54]
        total55 += arr[i+55]
        total56 += arr[i+56]
        total57 += arr[i+57]
        total58 += arr[i+58]
        total59 += arr[i+59]
        total60 += arr[i+60]
        total61 += arr[i+61]
        total62 += arr[i+62]
        total63 += arr[i+63]
        total64 += arr[i+64]
        total65 += arr[i+65]
        total66 += arr[i+66]
        total67 += arr[i+67]
        total68 += arr[i+68]
        total69 += arr[i+69]
        total70 += arr[i+70]
        total71 += arr[i+71]
        total72 += arr[i+72]
        total73 += arr[i+73]
        total74 += arr[i+74]
        total75 += arr[i+75]
        total76 += arr[i+76]
        total77 += arr[i+77]
        total78 += arr[i+78]
        total79 += arr[i+79]
        total80 += arr[i+80]
        total81 += arr[i+81]
        total82 += arr[i+82]
        total83 += arr[i+83]
        total84 += arr[i+84]
        total85 += arr[i+85]
        total86 += arr[i+86]
        total87 += arr[i+87]
        total88 += arr[i+88]
        total89 += arr[i+89]
        total90 += arr[i+90]
        total91 += arr[i+91]
        total92 += arr[i+92]
        total93 += arr[i+93]
        total94 += arr[i+94]
        total95 += arr[i+95]
        total96 += arr[i+96]
        total97 += arr[i+97]
        total98 += arr[i+98]
        total99 += arr[i+99]
    return total0+total1+total2+total3+total4+total5+total6+total7+total8+total9+total10+total11+total12+total13+total14+total15+total16+total17+total18+total19+total20+total21+total22+total23+total24+total25+total26+total27+total28+total29+total30+total31+total32+total33+total34+total35+total36+total37+total38+total39+total40+total41+total42+total43+total44+total45+total46+total47+total48+total49+total50+total51+total52+total53+total54+total55+total56+total57+total58+total59+total60+total61+total62+total63+total64+total65+total66+total67+total68+total69+total70+total71+total72+total73+total74+total75+total76+total77+total78+total79+total80+total81+total82+total83+total84+total85+total86+total87+total88+total89+total90+total91+total92+total93+total94+total95+total96+total97+total98+total99
```

results:
[image]
The numbers add up correctly since 10 million is a multiple of both 10 and 100, so the functionality checks out. Now to performance:

You may want to jump to conclusions and say: "WOW, unrolling increased speed by 2 to 2.5x! let's use it everywhere!"
The problem is the simplicity of the function. It's just one addition! no switch statements, no multiplications, nothing! By the time you add those, the 2.5x performance gain is gone too. Your efforts will be much better spent in trying to parallelize the code to run on multiple threads. Have a look at this post to see a very similar 2.5x performance gain with multi-threading:
[Increasing CPU usage with Python during for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77325423/increasing-cpu-usage-with-python-during-for-loops/77334010#77334010)
The advantage of the multi-threaded approach is that you can actually use your resources (CPU and memory bandwidth) rather than relying on decades-old tricks with questionable benefits on modern hardware.

Edit2: Here is proof for unrolling not making a difference in a very slightly different use case:
Imagine instead of just wanting to calculate the sum, you want the calculate sum of the cubes for the numbers in the array. We can modify the functions like:

```
cpdef  loop_sum(double [::1] arr):
    cdef unsigned int i = 0
    cdef double total = 0
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        total += arr[i]**3
    return total

cpdef  unroll_10_sum(double [::1] arr):
    cdef unsigned int i = 0, shape = arr.shape[0]
    cdef double total0 = 0, total1 = 0, total2 = 0, total3 = 0, total4 = 0, total5 = 0, total6 = 0, total7 = 0, total8 = 0, total9 = 0
    for i in range(0,shape,10):
        total0 += arr[i]**3
        total1 += arr[i+1]**3
        total2 += arr[i+2]**3
        total3 += arr[i+3]**3
        total4 += arr[i+4]**3
        total5 += arr[i+5]**3
        total6 += arr[i+6]**3
        total7 += arr[i+7]**3
        total8 += arr[i+8]**3
        total9 += arr[i+9]**3
    return total0+total1+total2+total3+total4+total5+total6+total7+total8+total9
```

Unsurprisingly enough all methods now have the same execution time since power or multiplication are not single-cycle instructions and cost way more than simple addition.
[image]
The moral of the story remains the same: Don't try to be too smart on modern hardware, most of the "tricks" you read about were designed decades ago and make no practical difference today. The only arcane knowledge that still holds true is branchless programming in my experience.

Comment: I appreciate all the tips with how to properly analyze python code/other optimization tips.  I understand this case is fairly simple, but it still seems like a useful strategy for squeezing out extra performance. Even in a multithreaded application, this could be used within each thread? (Unless you would create 10,000,000 threads to process each element). Also I should have mentioned I used numpy arrays. Does this reduce the bounds checking and other overhead done by python? Seriously thanks for all the help.

Comment: To be completely honest I'm not sure which specific checks are performed when using numpy arrays vs lists, but I imagine they are similar given that even indexing a numpy array can result in out-of-bounds/wraparound. I ran some ad hoc tests and funny enough accessing lists is slightly faster when using Python (but numpy arrays are much faster when using Cython). Also using 10million threads is pointless since you then need to add all of those together in a single thread (aggregation step), making your program effectively single-threaded, but with a massive overhead for creating so many threads

Comment: Regarding your point about unrolling being a "useful strategy" it entirely depends on what the code is running on. Again, modern architectures have out-of-order execution units and branch predictors, which effectively parallelize/unroll basic loops with predictable patterns that don't have too many dependencies. If you run the same code on a micro controller (Arduino or similar) you may get massive performance boosts since obviously none of what I said exists there, but again, depends on the cost of the increment + comparison (i++ and i<taget) vs cost of computation in each iteration.

Comment: See the updated response with an example of doing slightly more expensive calculations.

Comment: Great! I appreciate the updates and this post has been super helpful. Funnily enough branchless programming is one of the optimization techniques not mentioned in the textbook. :')

Comment: You may want to read this article then: https://dev.to/jobinrjohnson/branchless-programming-does-it-really-matter-20j4 . They do however mention that such tricks should be reserved for time-critical applications only (things like high-frequency trading, "real-time" operation systems, image processing, etc.)